# Rocket Throttle vs. Jet Throttle

Tags: rockets, engine-design, turbomachinery

One of the drawbacks of jet engines is that they suffer from turbo lag, whereby a throttle change will take some amount of time to translate to a change in thrust due to the momentum of the turbine itself.

I've never heard liquid-fuel rocket engines discussed with this drawback, even though they are fed by turbopumps.  Isn't turbo lag a pandemic problem in all turbomachinery, and if so, why does it not affect the ability of a liquid-fueld rocket to respond quickly to throttle changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most large liquid-fueled engines, if they throttle at all, follow a simple throttle program, either with a single large step-down or gradual reduction to manage acceleration limits as a stage gets lighter. In these cases, a lag time of a second or two is of little consequence.

The major exception to this is in engines used for powered descent such as the [Merlins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)#Merlin_1D) on SpaceX's [Falcon 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9). In this case, the descent algorithm must "plan ahead" knowing the effect of throttle lag. Assuming that the system has access to good test data regarding the throttle lag, it's not too difficult to do this under computer control.

Turbine lag is only a problem in jet engines because, at the points when throttle management is most time sensitive (takeoffs and, especially, landings), the throttle is being driven by a human. Humans are pretty good at this -- thousands of airliners land safely every day -- but computers are better.

The rocket engines that have been landed by humans under manual control, as far as I know, have all been smaller pressure-fed engines with no turbopump lag to deal with.

Comment: Also note RCS thrusters, that can fire in very short pulses. These are usually pressure-fed and use monopropellant.

Comment: examples of rocket engines landed under manual control?